# TypeError: get_dummies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drop_first'

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

Here's something I dont understand. When I run this:

```py
dataframe['col_name'].str.get_dummies(sep='|', drop_first=True)
```

I get: `TypeError: get_dummies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'drop_first'` which makes no sense to me when I read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies)...

I must be missing something. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is that because there are two implementations of `get_dummies`? I also saw this:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html

Comment: you can also try `help(dataframe['col_name'].str.get_dummies)` in an interpreter to read the exact doc string of the method you are using.

Comment: Looks like there are indeed two implementations with different arguments. Looks like I can't both get the separator and drop_first to avoid colinearity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `get_dummies`:

1. [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)
2. [pandas.Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html?highlight=get_dummies#pandas.Series.str.get_dummies)

The one you are using is the second one which does not have `drop_first`

Comment: OK, thanks. It's really a pitty that the series implementation does not include other parameters such as prefix, drop_first... I don't see why they wouldn't apply.